# Reference inner class in Visualforce component

Tags: visualforce-component

I'm trying to build a VF component that references an attribute that is an instance of an inner class. I followed the suggestion [here on the Apex boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Error-using-inner-class-in-component-attribute/td-p/147856) but it does not compile for me using V28.0. *(Note the boards post was about lists of inner class objects - I only need a single instance)*

Interface, Apex class, VF component follow:

```
public interface VFComponentAttributable {
// To make inner classes available as VF component attributes
// http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Error-using-inner-class-in-component-attribute/td-p/147856
}

public with sharing class Foo {
   public class InnerBar implements VFComponentAttributable{
      public String  myVbl {get; set;}
  }
}    


<apex:component >
<!-- Generates compiler error 'Unknown property VFComponentAttributable.myVbl' -->
<apex:attribute name="bar"                      description="instance of inner class"
                type="VFComponentAttributable"          required="true"/>

<apex:outputText value="{!bar.myVbl}"/>  


<!-- This doesnt work either, generates compiler error  'Apex class InnerBar does not exist
<apex:attribute name="bar"                      description="instance of inner class"
                type="Foo.InnerBar" required="true"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!bar.myVbl}"/>             -->
```

I know I can refactor and make the inner class an outer class and it will work but I'd rather not if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've run across this as well and also resorted to refactoring my inner-class to the top level. The documentation isn't clear on this, but considering that the type attribute is considered limited, I think it's fair to assume that only top-level classes are supported. From the Visualforce Developer's Guide (pg. 285):

**Only** the following data types are
allowed as values for the type attribute:

- Primitives, such as String, Integer, or Boolean.
- sObjects, such as Account, My_Custom_Object__c, or the generic sObject type.
- **One-dimensional** lists, specified using array-notation, such as String[], or Contact[].
- Maps, specified using type="map". You don't need to specify the map's specific data type.
- Custom Apex types (**classes**).

Comment: Thanks @Adam; I was forlornly hoping for a miracle here from one of the gang.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that your Component is receiving an instance of `VFComponentAttributable` which does not have the `myVbl` field.

If you change your `VFComponentAttributable` and `Foo` definitions to the following it should work.

```
public interface VFComponentAttributable 
{
    // To make inner classes available as VF component attributes
    // http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Error-using-inner-class-in-component-attribute/td-p/147856
    String getMyVbl();
    void setMyVbl(String value);
}

public with sharing class Foo 
{
    public class InnerBar implements VFComponentAttributable
    {
        private String  myVbl;

        public String getMyVbl()
        {
            return myVbl;
        }

        public void setMyVbl(String value)
        {
            myVbl = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alex -- I know you answered this long ago and I should have responded as your answer is correct and works fine (having just tried it). I've been stewing over this for some time but finally had a chance to revisit this on a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Why not in Foo:

```
Public foo{

    Public class innerBar{
    //etc
    }

    Public innerBar myBar {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: Yes, this would work in some use cases but my component is being invoked within a `apex:repeat` that is traversing a list of InnerBar so an instance of foo doesn't know which instance of InnerBar is being passed to the component.