# Component inner class variables not binding

Tags: apex

I have a component inside a VF page. The component has an inner class which is a wrapper containing a custom object and a text field. On the component, I am iterating over a list of wrappers. The text field is an input field on the component, however when I press a command button, the value does not bind to the text field. The wrapper list and the inner class variables have getters and setters.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, although you have done a good job explaining the issue, nothing explains a problem better than sharing the code you have so far.  This will allow others to try to isolate anything in the code that may be causing an issue.

Comment: be sure you're not running afoul of this limitation - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/reference-inner-class-in-visualforce-component

Answer (score 1):

In order for the value to be sent to the controller the command button must have some sort of ajax action assigned to it AND a rerender. Try adding `rerender="faketag"` to to the button.

This is just a guess but a common reason for this issue. Posting your code would be very helpful.

Comment: You can also just use `rerender=""`.