# Unable to save Lightning Component because of Save error for Custom Apex Class type attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bug, aura-attribute

I'm trying to create a Lightning Component and there is a Custom Apex Controller class with a child class in it.

But I'm receiving an error like this:

**Failed to save undefined: No TYPE named apex://MyAccountController.wChildItem[] found : [markup://vctm:AccCtrl]: Source**

The code for my Lightning Component looks like this:

**Code for .cmp file**:

```
<aura:component controller="MyAccountController">
    <!-- Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="children" type="MyAccountController.wChildItem[]" />
...
...
</aura:component>
```

**Code for APEX Class**:

```
public with sharing class MyAccountController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public  static  wChildItem[]    findRecords() {
        List<wChildItem> items  = new List<wChildItem>();
    ...
        ...
        return items;
    }

    public class wChildItem {
        @AuraEnabled
        public  string  sname   { get;set; }

        @AuraEnabled
        public  string  stype   { get;set; }

        public wChildItem(string n, string t) {
            sname   = n;
            stype       = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I keep getting the no TYPE cannot be found error on save? What is a workaround for this error?

Comment: can you check whether your class exist or not from setup->apex class because above code working for me.

Comment: Yes the class exists. Its compiled as well and is Valid and active as well.

Comment: @VarunC What version are you using ?What is the tool you are using ?I mean eclipse .mavens or force.com UI

Comment: I'm using Developer Console, and the API version of Lightning Component and Apex class both is 35.0

Comment: @VarunC have you checked class existence from developer console or Apex Class section?

Comment: both places. In my code if I simply remove the aura:attribute line and save with Component having its controller set to class, it saves correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualforce Components have a problem where they can't have attributes that reference an inner class as their type. You might be seeing something similar with your Lightning Component.

See this question: [Reference inner class in Visualforce component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/reference-inner-class-in-visualforce-component)

Try breaking `wChildItem` out into its own class.

You also may need to use your namespace when referencing your inner class, if you didn't pick a namespace, your namespace is likely "c".

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_apex.htm

`<aura:attribute name="children" type="c.wChildItem[]" />`

Comment: Actually I've already tried that as well. With that the issue I've is, i couldn't use List/Array of items as Attribute in Lightning Component. I try to save the code this way `<aura:attribute name="children" type="wChildItem[]" />` but after save it revert automatically back to this  `<aura:attribute name="children" type="wChildItem" />` - noticed the saved version is not a List of wChildItem but becomes a singular item.

Comment: You'll need to use your namespace, which might just be "c". See this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_apex.htm. So try `<aura:attribute name="children" type="c.wChildItem[]" />`

Comment: Thanks ... That worked. Silly me, don't know how I missed that part of the documentation :-( ... I would suggest adding the document link from your comments to your Answer above, as that is necessary for making it a complete answer ...

Comment: Hey @frontendloader - I'm back with same issue again. I tried using this same code but now with a Namespace of my organization `<aura:attribute name="children" type="myns.wChildItem[]" />` and it auto reverts back to `<aura:attribute name="children" type="myns.wChildItem" />` a singular item instead of datatype being an Array. Can you tell me why it is doing that? It works fine if i replace my namespace with `c`.