# Can't Access 2nd Level in 'InvocableVariable' Object

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, callout, invocablevariable

I've got at flow that makes a callout and returns (to the flow) an object defined in apex (`@InvocableVariable`):

```
public class MostOuter {
   @InvocableVariable public Inner1 var1;
   @InvocableVariable public List<Inner2> var2;
}

public class Inner1 {
   @InvocableVariable public String var1;
   @InvocableVariable public String var2;
}

public class Inner2 {
   @InvocableVariable public String var1;
   @InvocableVariable public List<String> var2;
   @InvocableVariable public Inner3 var3;
}

public class Inner3 {
   @InvocableVariable public String var1;
   @InvocableVariable public String var2;
}
```

The issue we've got, is that in our flow, we can't access data more than one level deep  - in this case: `MostOuter.var1`. Trying to access `MostOuter.var1.var1` results in a flow compilation error.

Is this a result of incorrect setup or is it just another Salesforce limitation?

Thank You

Comment: this might help : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_extend_apex_type.htm&type=5

Comment: YES - a combination of putting the classes in their own file (outer class) and adding ```@AuraEnabled``` to all definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Apex types within the invocable request or response, there are some limitations as documented in [Considerations for Apex-Defined Types](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_apex_data_type.htm&type=5)

- No inner classes - so, in your case, `Inner1`, `Inner2`, `Inner3` need to be outer classes
- Fields in those inner-now-outer classes must be annotated with `@AuraEnabled`

You would reference the inner objects by declaring variables of type `Apex-defined`

There is a [comprehensive example](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_extend_apex_type.htm&type=5) showing how to declare the Apex classes where the response includes an inner Apextype. The example can be a bit misleading because it talks about callouts and JSON but there is no requirement that your use case involve either callouts or JSON.

*This reminds me of [the restriction with VF component attributes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/reference-inner-class-in-visualforce-component), which if an ApexType, had to be an outer class, no inner classes were supported*